# Normal ESR Values for Capacitors of Various Types

Tags: esr

I am working on a light detection preamp board that went bad. The circuit uses a chopper stabilized opamp TLC2652. Does it have a reputation for being fragile?

Anyway, as usual, I went around to check the capacitors. I found the 4 orange and 2 white capacitors are reading about 15-18 Ohms, the green Sprague 150D tantalum reading 1.6 Ohm. The image of the board in included below. Are these values about right?

[image: Light Detector Board]

Answer (score 1):

For ESR those are probably okay, of course in-circuit they may not read correctly but if you have  good ESR meter it's probably close enough.

Anything that's connected to cables etc. is potentially at risk, and more so if it's CMOS (or very high frequency bipolar- which this stuff isn't), or older CMOS (which the 4051 is). You can replace both those chips inexpensively and put machined pin sockets in there while you're at it.

What's that crud on the lower orange capacitor leads? Did it get wet? Looks like residue elsewhere on the board too.

Comment: Oh, I unsoldered one end of each capacitor in order to measure them.

Comment: Fixed. It is the 4051. Staring with intermittent errors then doesn't work at all. Might be a bonding wire that became loose inside the package.

Comment: @user1596683 Thanks for the feedback. It's 21 years old so I guess it lasted fairly well.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am glad it is this chip. The chopper stabilized op amp TLC2652 is not available in local stores. Ordering from China would take 1 mo and $8.